# How to show List Items below Text Field in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I am trying to take input and whenever i click on the button it should add that input in the list and show below the text field. Basically i am trying to view current updated list. All the inputs should be shown one by one below The text field. How can i implement this ?

Here is the logic

```
export default function App() {
    const [enteredGoalText, setEnteredGoalText] = useState('');
    const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);

    function goalInputHandler(enteredText){
        setEnteredGoalText(enteredText);
    }

    function addGoalHandler(){
        setCourseGoals((currentCourseGoals) => [
          ...currentCourseGoals,
          enteredGoalText,
        ]);
    }

  return (
    <View style={styles.AppContainer}>
      <View style={styles.Container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.TxtInput} placeholder="Your Course Goal!" onClickText={goalInputHandler}/>
        <Button title="Add Goal" onPress={addGoalHandler}/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.goalsContainer}>
        {courseGoals.map((goal) => <Text key={goal}>{goal}</Text>)}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to your code. You are using the wrong methods to store the values entered in the TextInput.

Please have a look at the code below.

```
const [enteredGoalText, setEnteredGoalText] = useState('');
  const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);

  function goalInputHandler(enteredText) {
    setEnteredGoalText(enteredText);
  }

  function addGoalHandler() {
    setCourseGoals(currentCourseGoals => [
      ...currentCourseGoals,
      enteredGoalText,
    ]);
    setEnteredGoalText('');
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.AppContainer}>
      <View style={styles.Container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.TxtInput}
          value={enteredGoalText}
          placeholder="Your Course Goal!"
          onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
        />
        <Button title="Add Goal" onPress={addGoalHandler} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.goalsContainer}>
        {courseGoals.map((goal, index) => (
          <Text style={{color: 'black'}} key={index}>
            {goal}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```